# How to linearize or convexify this max min objective?

Tags: convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I have an objective function given by

$\underset{a_{c,i}}{\max}\hspace{1mm}\underset{i,i=1,\cdots,M}{\min}\hspace{1mm}\frac{s_i(a_{c,i})}{d_i}$

$c=1,2,\cdots,N$, $i=1,2,\cdots,M$

$s_i=\sum_{c=1}^Na_{c,i}f_{c,i}$ with $0\le a_{c,i}\le1$

where, $f_{c,i}\ge0$ (are known)

What can we say about the convexity of this objective function

$d_i$'s are $>0$ and $s_i(a_{c,i})>0$

Are $\max \min$ optimization objective nonlinear/nonconvex?

If so, how can I linearize/convexify it?

Comment: It depends on how are your functions

Comment: Your problem is equivalent to choosing $(a,b,x) \in \mathbb{R}^3$ to maximize $x$ subject to $s_i(a,b)/d_i\geq x$ for all $i \in \{1, ..., M\}$.   This is a convex optimization problem if the $s_i(a,b)/d_i$ functions are concave over $(a,b) \in \mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: @mlainz, I have edited my post. Could you be more specific now!!

Comment: @Michael, please have a look at my edit. what would be your oservation now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a=(a_{c,i})$ for $c \in \{1, ..., N\}, i \in \{1, ..., M\}$.  You have concave functions $g_i(a)$ for $i \in \{1, ..., M\}$. You want to solve: 
$$ \max_{a \in [0,1]^{NM}} \min_{i\in \{1, ..., M\}} g_i(a)$$
Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$.  Your problem is equivalent to choosing $(a,x)$ to solve: 
\begin{align}
\mbox{Maximize:} & \quad x\\
\mbox{Subject to:} & \quad g_i(a) \geq x \quad \forall i \in \{1, ..., N\} \\
& \quad a_{c,i} \in [0,1] \quad \forall c \in \{1, ..., N\}, i \in \{1, ..., M\}\\
&\quad x \in \mathbb{R}
\end{align}
This is a convex optimization problem. If your  $g_i(a)$ functions are linear then this is a linear program.

---

In fact your $g_i(a)$ functions are not only linear but have a very simple structure: 
$$ g_i(a) = \frac{1}{d_i}\sum_{c=1}^N a_{c,i}f_{c,i}  $$
with given constants $d_i>0, f_{c,i}\geq 0$. So each $g_i(a)$ function uses its own variables $(a_{1,i}, a_{2,i}, ..., a_{N,i})$ and the solution is trivial: 
$$a^*_{c,i}=1 \quad \forall i,c $$
$$x^* = \min_{i \in \{1, ..., N\}} g_i(a^*)$$